# Where is AppArmor's Log File?

Tags: kali-linux, logs, apparmor, sandbox

I'm trying to scan the application Firefox with AppArmor sandbox, however I don't know where the location of the log file is. I use Kali Linux, and there are so many directories with log files.

I also see an error message in my console, related to a problem with a parser from a Python library. I registered an issue at Gitlab, and the feedback seems indicate that I used the wrong log file.

I used `sudo aa-genprof -f /var/log/journal/<random_string>/system.journal firefox`, and it says to open the application. The problem is when I give the command to scan the application to generate the profile. Assuming the problem is the log file, what's the correct log file?

Comment: Could you post a link to your issue request?